# How could I automate the secure setting in deployment of Linux VM's?

Tags: python, shell, devops

I have a Windows environment where I manege many Linux servers, so I'm studying python to automate process, including the new VM's deployment.

> I tried to copy the /etc/login.defs of a machine that contains all the
>   polices requested to the VM

```
import subprocess as sub
comand = str("user@localhost:/etc/log.defs user@vmhost:/etc/log.defs")
sub.run(["scp", comand])
```

I've already set ssh keys and did tests in linux lab's, but I don't how to do it in Windows, if someone has another solution totally different from mine, please give a advise.

Comment: Consider looking into automation tools such as [Ansible](https://ansible.com) (more generally, "configuration management tools"), which are designed explicitly to handle these sorts of tasks.

Comment: Do you need just startup or shutdown the remote linux machines or do you need another complex tasks?